# check db_query returns empty

Tags: php, drupal-7

How to check the query result returns empty or not.  I found no other way and tried this but still getting issue.

```
$ww = db_query("SELECT item1,id FROM db_item WHERE db_item.id = '".$record->data1."'" );
$d=0;
foreach($ww as $ee){
        $d=11;
        $ed =  $ee->item1;
        $options2.="$ed";
}
if($d!=11){
        $options2.="No ITEM added!";
}
```

EDIT

```
 $ww = db_query("SELECT item1,id FROM db_item WHERE db_item.id = '".$record->data1."'" );
  if(!empty($ww)){ 
  foreach($ww as $ee){
        $d=11;
        $ed =  $ee->item1;
        $options2.="$ed";
    }
 }
      else{
        $options2.="No ITEM added!";
}
```

Comment: `if(!empty($ww)){ //not empty } else { //empty }`

Comment: i tried but still returns the issue back..

Comment: @Daan ; but the db_query returns not a single value, it is used for iterating the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`db_query()` function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) returns a [`DatabaseStatementInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/interface/DatabaseStatementInterface/7), which has the [`fetchAllAssoc`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3ArowCount/7) method available. You can use that method to get an array that can have empty characteristics for the PHP `empty()` function:

```
$ww = db_query("SELECT item1,id FROM db_item WHERE db_item.id = '".$record->data1."'" );
$results = $ww->fetchAllAssoc('id');
if (!empty($results)) {
    // results not empty
} else {
    // results empty
}
```

Note I avoided the [`rowCount`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3ArowCount/7) method on purpose because it is only meant for `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, or `DELETE` queries.